# JSF p:password validation and feedback only works after page is reloaded

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, passwords

I am writing a page where a user can change his password. First he needs to entry his old password and a validator is called .When the password is correct two password fields get enabled and he can type in a new password and needs to repeat it.
I am using the p:password component from primefaces 4.0 for this.
In the first password field where he can entry his new password i have a attribute feedback="true". The problem here is that when i call the site for the first time there is no feedback output. It only appears when i reload the page and type in the password field again.
Also the validator validatePwd1 of the password field is not called.
In the repeat password field i have the same problem with the validator.

Is it possible to reload only this two components after the page is loaded with ajax or something? Or is there a better way to fix this error?

Here is my page:

```
                                  <p:row id="RowConfirmOldPw" rendered="#{userSettingBean.showPasswordFields}">

                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['usersett_account_oldPwd']}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:password id="oldPwd" value="#{userSettingBean.oldPassword}" >
                                                <f:validator validatorId="passwordEqualValidator"/>
                                                <f:ajax event="keyup" render="oldPwdMessage pwd1 pwd2"/>
                                            </p:password>
                                            <p:watermark for="oldPwd" value="#{msg['usersett_account_oldPwd']}"/>

                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:message id="oldPwdMessage" for="oldPwd"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>



                                    <p:row id="RowTypeNewPassword">

                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['usersett_account_newPwd']}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{userSettingBean.password1}" 
                                            disabled="#{userSettingBean.disableNewPassword}" feedback="true" validator="#{userSettingBean.validatePwd1}">
                                                <f:ajax event="keyup" render="pwdMatchMessage"/>
                                            </p:password>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>

                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['usersett_account_reenter']}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{userSettingBean.password1}" 
                                            disabled="#{userSettingBean.disableNewPassword}" validator="#{userSettingBean.validateMatch}">
                                                <f:ajax event="keyup" render="pwdMatchMessage buttonSaveAccount"/>
                                            </p:password>

                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:message id="pwdMatchMessage" for="pwd2"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now.
When you use primefaces, you always have to take
the `<p:ajax>` tag. In my code I also used `<f:ajax>`.
This two tags do not work together.
When i replaced the `<f:ajax>` tags with `<p:ajax>` it worked!